# How to use flock on Linux

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mutex, flock

I am looking at the flock docs:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/flock.htm

https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

temp_dir="$HOME/temperton/tmp";
mkdir -p "$temp_dir"

(

  flock -x "$temp_dir/a"
  echo '111'

) &

(

  flock -x "$temp_dir/a"
  echo '222'

) &
```

but when I run it I get this error:

> ```
> flock: bad file descriptor: '/home/ratt/temperton/tmp/a'
> flock: 111
> bad file descriptor: '/home/ratt/temperton/tmp/a'
> 222
> ```

Comment: That is not how flock works. You need to supply both a file to lock and a command. Please look at [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) manual page, it contains usage examples.

Comment: By *not* including a command to run, you're telling it to do the file descriptor based locking, but you're forgetting a couple of very important things for that to work. So yeah, look at the example in the man page again.

Answer (score 4):

The 'flock' is the most useful then operates with a file descriptor. You should also provide a command to execute if locking on on file/dir-name. I guess, internally it works as the following:

```sh
    exec 4<$name # open
    flock 4
    <your_command_here>
    exec 4<&-    # close
```

In your example you can replace locks with

```sh
    flock $temp_dir sleep 5s
```

to check the difference.

Comment: if you say exec 4<$name it will create a file called '4' AND also set the descriptor value to 4.  But if you say exec 4<>$name it will just set the descriptor and not create the unnecessary 4 file.

Comment: no, this does not create file named '4' ;)

Comment: I could show you a video showing otherwise ;).  It's possible it's a linux thing within a docker container for me though to be fair.